# C# Calculate Price and Quantity column in DataGridView & Display to Total Column

Tags: c#

Hi everyone I wanted to calculate the following in DataGridView If button " Calculate" is pressed Price column and Quantity column will multiply and it will be displayed in Total Column. Below is the code for adding Item name,Price and Quantity. Any help would be appreciated Thank you!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the dataGridView cell value into decimal or double data type first then round up with `Math.Round` function into 2 or 3 decimal point whatever you need.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iNewRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value = textBox1.Text;
    dataGridView1.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells["price"].Value = textBox2.Text;
    dataGridView1.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells["qty"].Value = textBox3.Text;

    dataGridView1.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells["price"].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells["qty"].Value), 2);
}
```